# After connecting my App to a library project, R won't get generated

Tags: android, android-library

I have an Android library project for all common things shared between my projects. Today I attached this library to a new project and finally this new app stops generating R and all Activities encounter errors. When I detached library everything goes OK. And also all previously connected apps compile and build with no problem. So I think that something is wrong between this project and library project. I googled this problem and did all the things in other similar threads in SOF but nothing solved this problem.

Any Idea?

Comment: Do any classes in the library have an import for R which you've added manually amongst its other imports? If so you might want to remove that import, clean and build again.

Comment: What is the android versions of those two projects..?

Comment: min sdk 8 and target sdk 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this problem, I noticed that I have one @+id/... in my values/styles.xml file and after removing that line everything goes OK. 
The question is why this is NOT documented anywhere that this is not allowed and why it generates no error until connecting project to a library project?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the R.java file and clean the project. I had this procedure help me before. Make sure your project doesn't have errors though, otherwise it tends not to recreate it.

Comment: The projects and library compile and run OK before connecting together. After connection project won't compile because its R.java is not generated.

Comment: Is everything ok in java build path? Also did you try clean? Make sure there is no errors in your resources.

Comment: Yes. They work OK even after detach! I did try clean and there is no error in resources! Strange!

Comment: So when you detach it generates R.java?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40223/discussion-between-ali-behzadian-nejad-and-serge)